# Laravel Dusk Login Authentication failed

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-dusk2

I'm trying to test my login but failing with the following approach. Any suggestions why I'm not able to login the user?

```
/** @test */
public function login_into_lerova()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'email' => 'max.mustermann@smartgate.ch',
        'password' => bcrypt('normal'),
    ]);

    $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user){

        $browser->visit(url(route('login')))
                ->type('email', $user->email)
                ->type('password','normal')
                ->press('@login-button')
                ->assertAuthenticatedAs($user);

    });
}
```

**Receiving the following error:**

```
1) Tests\Browser\LoginTest::login_into_lerova
The currently authenticated user is not who was expected.
Failed asserting that Array &0 () is identical to Array &0 (
    'id' => 1
    'className' => 'App\User'
).
```

Cheers, 
**Stan**

[Screenshot-Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0u9M.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to follow this tutorial about dusk and you will be clear what is your issue is, 
[Laravel Dusk Tutorial](http://www.techalyst.com/links/read/110/how-to-use-laravel-dusk)

Comment: Hey Akram, thanks for your answer. I saw this tutorial before. But I don't want to check if the route is correct, I would like to check that the user is Authenticated. Because If you get logged in with the wrong user the path is still correct. Cheers, Stan